# Lisp association list error

Tags: lisp

I write the code that insert cons cell into association list.
For example, there is association list

```
((1 . a) (3 . c) (4 . d))
```

and I want to insert cons cell `(2 . b)` then this program produces

```
((1  a) (2 . b) (3 . c) (4 . d))
```

but my code raises an exception

```
(car L) should be a lambda expression
```

below is my code

```
(defun INSERTCELL (R L)
  (cond ((< (car L) (car R)) cons((car L) INSERTCELL(R (cdr L))))
        (t cons(R L))))
```

`R` is `(2 . b)`, and `L` is `((1 . a) (3 . c) (4 . d))` so `R` should be inserted into `L`.

Comment: Functions are called like `(cons args...)` not `cons(args...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function calls in Lisp are [cons cells](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/03_abab.htm):

```
(cons 1 2)
==> (1 . 2)
```

If you fix your code:

```
(defun insertcell (R L)
  (cond ((< (caar L) (car R)) (cons (car L) (insertcell R (cdr L))))
        (t (cons R L))))
```

it works:

```
(insertcell '(2 . b) '((1 . a) (3 . c) (4 . d)))
==> ((1 . A) (2 . B) (3 . C) (4 . D))
```

Note that you also need to do `(caar L)`, not `(car L)` because `L` is an alist, so to access the first key you need to call `car` twice.

Comment: I think the op would benefit from having pointed out that they are understandably enough slipping into func(arg1 arg2) syntax three (at least) places. Hell, if I right enough JS even I can do that. :)

Answer (score 1):

[SDS's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36457746/1281433) takes care of the typographical issue in your code, as well as some of the other bugs.  That said, I think it's worth noting that there might be other ways to do this.  First, association lists don't have to be stored in order.  If you don't need yours to be in order, then you can simply use [**acons**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_acons.htm) to add the new element to the beginning:

```
(let ((alist '((1 . a) (3 . c) (4 . d))))
  (acons 2 'b alist))
;=> ((2 . B) (1 . A) (3 . C) (4 . D))
```

If you do need to maintain the sorting condition, one option would be to use the approach above, and then [**sort**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_sort_.htm) the list afterward.  That's probably a bit overkill, though, since you already know that the association list is sorted, and you only need to put the new element in its place.  To that end, you can use the built in [**merge**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_merge.htm) function to merge your association list and the new element (by wrapping it in a list, so it's a association  list of one element):

```
(let ((alist (copy-list '((1 . a) (3 . c) (4 . d))))
      (new (list (cons 2 'b))))
  (merge 'list alist new '< :key 'car))
;=> ((1 . A) (2 . B) (3 . C) (4 . D))
```

or

```
(let ((alist '((1 . a) (3 . c) (4 . d))))
  (merge 'list (copy-list alist) (copy-list '((2 . b)))
         '< :key 'car))
;=> ((1 . A) (2 . B) (3 . C) (4 . D))
```

Note that merge is destructive (that is, it's allowed to modify its arguments), and that's why I used **copy-list** here to get fresh data.  In your case, since you're probably building up the list incrementally, it's probably OK, *as long* as you save the result.  E.g.,

```
(defun insert-cell (key value alist)
  (merge 'list alist (list (cons key value))
         '< :key 'car))
```

```
(let ((alist '()))
  (setf alist (insert-cell 1 'a alist))
  (setf alist (insert-cell 4 'd alist))
  (setf alist (insert-cell 3 'c alist))
  (setf alist (insert-cell 2 'b alist))
  alist)
;=> ((1 . A) (2 . B) (3 . C) (4 . D))
```