# I want to merge and sort two sorted lists with Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I want to merge and sort two sorted association lists with Common Lisp.
I made code. But result is not same with my thought.

```
(defun MERGEALIST (K L)
  (cond ((and (eq nil K) (eq nil L)) nil)
        ((eq nil K) L)
        ((eq nil L) K)
        ((<= (car (car K)) (car (car L)))
         (cons K (MERGEALIST (cdr K) L)))
        ((> (car (car K)) (car (car L)))
         (cons L (MERGEALIST K (cdr L))))))
```

Function's input `K` and `L` is sorted association lists. 
For example,

`K` is `((1 . a) (3 . c) (5 . e))`

`L` is `((2 . b) (4 . d))`.

I expected that result is `((1 . a) (2 . b) (3 . c) (4 . d) (5 . e))`.

But result is completely different.
Why this result is come out?
thanks.

Comment: Try changing the `(cons k ...)` and `(cons l ...)` in the last two cases to `(cons (car k) ...)` and `(cons (car l) ...)`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you got an answer to this in your earlier question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36457071/1281433.  The answer you've accepted here (to use the standard function **merge**), was described in [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36459061/1281433) there (disclaimer, that's my answer).

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: the answer with MERGE is only in addition. I've specifically answered his question with his code in the first part. I would think that his question was not about which existing function solves it, but how he get the code to work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify it a bit. The main change is like in the comment from jkiiski.

```
CL-USER 5 > (defun MERGEALIST (K L)
              (cond ((and (null K) (null L)) nil)
                    ((null K) L)
                    ((null L) K)
                    ((<= (caar K) (caar L))
                     (cons (car K) (MERGEALIST (cdr K) L)))
                    ((> (caar K) (caar L))
                     (cons (car L) (MERGEALIST K (cdr L))))))
MERGEALIST

CL-USER 6 > (mergealist '((1 . a) (3 . c) (5 . e)) '((2 . b) (4 . d)))
((1 . A) (2 . B) (3 . C) (4 . D) (5 . E))
```

The built-in function `merge` does it:

```
CL-USER 9 > (merge 'list
                   '((1 . a) (3 . c) (5 . e))
                   '((2 . b) (4 . d))
                   #'<
                   :key #'car)
((1 . A) (2 . B) (3 . C) (4 . D) (5 . E))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(cons K (MERGEALIST (cdr K) L))
```

Here you put the *complete* list `K` in front of the "rest" of your computation. You only want the first element of it (that you just tested to "come before" the first element of `L`):

```
(cons (car K) (MERGEALIST (cdr K) L))
```

Though note that you could simplify that a lot:

```
(defun merge-alists (k l)
  (cond 
    ;; Common case first, if both alists are not empty, then select
    ;; the first element of that alist, whose car is less. Then, recurse.
    ((and (consp k) (consp l))
         (if (<= (caar k) (caar l))
           (cons (car k) (merge-alists (cdr k) l))
           (cons (car l) (merge-alists k (cdr l)))))
    ;; One of the alists is empty, use either the not-empty one or ...
    ((consp k) k)
    ;; ... just the other (when k is empty or both are empty)
    (t l)))
```

*(The last two `cond` clauses could be simplified to `(t (or k l))` ... but that could be a bit too concise to be clearly understandable.)*

Or, as already pointed out, use `merge`.